# Pause execution for sometime at each solution to make animation visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have coded N-Queen problem using backtracking in javascript.

## **what I want to do?**

I want to spot execution of script for a second every time it reaches to solution and show the solution using animation.

## **what is the problem?**

code execution is so fast that i can not see any color transition.

here is a part of my code (where i want to spot execution of script for a second).
for full code please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/a603smud/1/

```
function placeQueen(row){
    for(var i=0;i<N && row<N;i++){
      chess[row][i] = 1;
      var temp = row*N+i+1;
      //place a Queen (red color)
      $('#'+temp).css("background-color","red");
      //check if place is safe
      if(check(row,i)){
        if(row==N-1){
           //place is safe and it is last row then
           //solution found 
           //stop execution for a second 
           //then continue
           print();
        }
        else{
          setTimeout(function(){
              placeQueen(row+1);
          },1000);
        }
      }
      //remove the Queen (backtracking)
      $('#'+temp).css("background-color","blue");
      chess[row][i]=0;
    }
}
```

Red color : queen is placed on the box
blue color : box is empty

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Open the code in the debugger in either Firefox or Chrome. That way you can just follow what happens step by step.

Comment: @ Norbert Yes i can do that using break points but i want to show this simulation to other people without using debbuger. i tried using setTimeout function but it is not working.

Comment: Your question should contain enough code to reproduce the error, even if there's a link to a fiddle.

Comment: @BSMP my code does not contain any error. i just want to stop execution of code for a second when it reaches to print() function. you can use break point to see my on the line when print() function is called.

Comment: @BSMP when you put break point this it will look like this http://picpaste.com/N-Queen-keW0JK78.PNG

Comment: Tried utilizing `setTimeout` ?

Comment: @guest271314 yes tried but it does not work

Comment: OK, "error" isn't the correct word here but you code still isn't doing what you want. The question should still contain enough code to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: @SurajTripathi Can describe _"it does not work"_ ? , include attempt with `setTimeout` at Question ? Where is `chess` defined ?

Comment: @guest271314 no i din. you can see the complete code on http://jsfiddle.net/a603smud/1/
i have edited my code to show my attempt with setTimeout

Comment: @SurajTripathi:  `setTimeout` doesn't stop execution. It will continue with the loop right after it scheduled that callback to be executed later.

Comment: You will need to rewrite this into a recursive solution, so that you can return from the function right after the timeout.

Comment: @Bergi: Then where should i put setTimeout or can you tell me any other way of doing it?

Comment: @SurajTripathi: You will need to get rid of that `for` loop. Use recursion with a state variable, or actual continuation callbacks. Then you can use `setTimeout` as you tried - notice that it doesn't return the result, you will need to use the callback.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep for example

Comment: @Norbert i tried that also.. because browser is always busy (busy waiting)...so it does not update UI.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi I will work on your suggestion.
i think that is the only way to do it.

Comment: Alternative idea/method: fading in/out: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp or CSS fade in/out: That way you do not sleep, but JS will have to wit for the fade to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @bergi and all for you valuable suggestions
**I used a array to store all the results and then using setInterval function simulated the result**.

```
var solutionArray = [];

// run the algorithm and do
solutionArray.push(tempResult);
// on every step

var counter=0;
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
    simulate(solutionArray[counter++]);
    if(counter>=92){
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        removeSimulation(solutionArray[counter]);
    },600);
}, 1000);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/a603smud/8/) is the link to the full code

Comment: Could you please remove those `print()` statements from your fiddle (and update the link)?